# Reading and storing values inside the file in mobiles which is generated from external device

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, mobile

i am trying to build a application in android.I should collect some data from external device [ This application is creating for the physics students who takes reading from any device for plotting graph]. My question is if i connect to that external device and to android mobiles through data cable connector will i able to store those read values into some file and store in mobile memory directly? will it automatically craets file in mobile or i need to write seperate code to create file and store values into it. As i told it is like a "origin" software. Physics students connects their external device to computer through  data cable connector then it will generate a file with the readings. Then they will import that file and plot the graph. I need to do same application in android.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should make your device as Android Accessory. Like your device will work as Android accessory and there will be one compatible app in side android device, and both can communicate with each other directly.

Please check this link http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html
And Arduino is the best board to develop such kind of Android accessory. As its having android accessory library available.

Comment: Can you explain me more clearly? External devices is like reading temperature or voltage etc. how i can achieve this?

Comment: Like you have to make your external device using Arduino board.

Comment: Please refer below link to get basic idea. http://blog.arduino.cc/2013/07/18/how-to-control-arduino-board-using-an-android-phone/#.UxRcY_mSyI4. Arduino is open source electronic prototyping hardware(having AtMega series micro controller). Its having it's own IDE to make embedded program. But making and flashing it to board is very easy. Now you can read sensors and send that data to Android device using AOA protocol.And check this link <http://arduino.cc/> to know more about Arduino.